# Expanding/Expansion of/on my point

Tags: vocabulary

I want to say: "I know it is important to expand on my point." (i.e. It is not enough to share my suggestion, I need to justify it, explain how this can be applied, etc.)
This is a perfectly valid sentence, but in this case I need to rephrase it. Which of the options below are idiomatic (a search online proved useless):

> I know expansion on my point is important.

> I know expanding on my point is important.

> I know expansion of my point is important.

> I know expanding of my point is important.

Comment: **To expand on your point** is fine. Alternatively, you want **to put/get your point across**.           https://ludwig.guru/s/to+expand+on+this+point

Comment: I know that "to expand on my point" is fine, I am asking about the 4 options below. How do they sound to you?

Comment: 1, 3 and 4 sound wrong. 2 sounds awkward. The words "expand on my/the/this point" seem immutable, though you can start with, "Expanding on..." as you might start with, "To expand on..."

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you